# Check if there is an ExternalStorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

**How can I check if WP8 phone has an External Storage (SD)?**

Comment: This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question). Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: @SonerGönül this is probably a single line check, so no I don't even know how to begin trying (beside searching the web, which I did)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the functionality you are looking for might be available in the Microsoft.Phone.Storage namespace. Keep in mind that the value returned will be null if there are no devices found.

```
var storageAssets = await ExternalStorage.GetExternalStorageDevicesAsync();
ExternalStorageDevice item = storageAssets.FirstOrDefault();
```

Information found here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.storage(v=vs.105).aspx
- http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-local-storage-windows

Good example from Microsoft:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that I already have, my question is how to check if that externalstoragedevice exists or not (if the device has a SD card)

Comment: @DanBarzilay I would assume it would return null if it didn't exist. I havn't dealt with external storage yet, but this seems like another good example from MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Works :) thanks, please edit the answer so future viewers could see it clearly and than i'll accept it.